# Use of moment generating function (MGF) for derivng closed form expression for pairwise error probability of space-time code

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

Would anyone recommend some resources on the use of the Moment Generating Function for deriving closed form expressions for the pairwise error probability of a given space-time modulation system?
Thanks

Comment: Your question is too vague/specific.

Comment: i am trying to evaluate the performance of a multi-antenna  communication system that uses space-time coding. To do so, i would need to derive a closed form expression for the **pairwise error probability** (PEP) which is the probability that the receiver would mistakenly decode (for exemple) Xa for Xb. To do so i have found in literature that the (MGF) approach is used. So i need some resources on the use of this method for this purpose.